# How do I position a certain UICollectionViewCell at a certain position even after the number of cells above change?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, flowlayout

I have a question about UICollectionView.

In the settingsViewController, a user can toggle a certain settings feature. If it's set to True, then there will be 4 cells above this particular UICollectionViewCell (let's call Cell A) in the MainViewController, making this cell location being close to the bottom. If it's false, then the number of cells above CellA will be 2, which will make the location of CellA somewhere in the middle of the screen. I know I can dynamically change the height of the 2 cells in a brute force way to force CellA to be at the fixed position. But I want the 2 cells above CellA to maintain the same height.

How do I keep the position of the CellA fixed despite the number of cells above changing back and forth between 2 and 4?

Any suggestion or ideas are very welcomed as well.

Thank you.